# Django search for all entries in Model

Tags: django

I'm using a simple queryset to return objects that are present in a `City`.

My `City` model is as follows:

```
class City(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The search form has two inputs, one is a text box and another is a dropdown to select the city. The default dropdown option is: `Please select a city`. Originally, I had done the following:

```
def search_page(request):
    if 'query' in request.GET and request.GET['query']:
        city = request.GET['city']
        if city == 'Please select a city':
            cit = 'New York'
        else:
            cit = city
        q = request.GET['query']
```

and it would search only in New York. However, I feel it's possible to search in all cities if `Please select a city` is the chosen option on submit. For this I tried the following

```
def search_page(request):
    if 'query' in request.GET and request.GET['query']:
        city = request.GET['city']
        if city == 'Please select a city':
            cit = City.objects.all()
        else:
            cit = city
        q = request.GET['query']
```

However, this gave me an error as follows:

`ProgrammingError at /search
operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...yes%')  AND "Appname_city"."name" =  (SELECT...`

The queryset to return the search results is:

```
ct = Classified.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=q) | Q(subcategory__parent__type__icontains=q) | Q(address__area__icontains=q) | Q(subcategory__name__icontains=q)).filter(active__icontains='yes').filter(address__city__name__exact=cit)
```

where Classified is:

```
class Classified(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=20, default=0)
    secondary_number = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=20, default=0, blank=True)
    image = S3DirectField(upload_to='s3direct', blank=True)
    NO = 'NO'
    YES = 'YES'
    APPROVAL = ((NO, 'no'), (YES, 'yes'))
    active = models.CharField(choices=APPROVAL, default=NO, max_length=3)
    verified = models.CharField(choices=APPROVAL, default=NO, max_length=3)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

EDIT: Adding code line that shows error:

```
 ct = paginate.page(1)
```

where the pagination is done as follows:

```
    paginate = Paginator(ct, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        ct = paginate.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        ct = paginate.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        ct = paginate.page(paginate.num_pages)
```

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: which is the code line that throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question and problem, I think you should do the following:

```
cit = City.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
```

then

```
.....filter(address__city__name__in=cit)
```

So first get the names of all the cities. After that, change your filtering from `__exact` to `__in`

Comment: This gives me an error as follows: `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`  in the same line of code as mention in Original post

Comment: Sorry, had made an error in one of the lines. Fixed this and it mostly worked. Need to fix some issues, and then it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your code in case of city from GET params was "Please select a city", then you assing a **queryset** containing all cities in your database.

```
if city == 'Please select a city':
    cit = City.objects.all()
```

When you do query like:

```
.filter(address__city__name__exact=cit)
```

cit is actually a queryset, which in turn Django ORM turns to subquery resulting something unwanted.

You probably need to have two queries, one that filters exact and one that filters by in - though in that case, is the filter even needed?